# Short Circuiting vs Multiple if's

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, short-circuiting

What are the differences between this:

```
if(a && b)
{
     //code
}
```

and this:

```
if(a)
{
     if(b)
     {
          //code
     }
}
```

From what I know `b` will only get evaluated in the first code block if `a` is true, and the second code block would be the same thing.

Are there any benefits of using one over the other? Code execution time? memory? etc.

Comment: Why would you care about execution time or memory? That's nuts. This is a clear case where one is likely to be cleaner and easier to understand than the other. Why would you even think about micro-optimizations?! The only optimizations that should be performed in the absence of demonstrated need are algorithmic optimizations.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well you have to choose one, might as well be the better one, if for whatever the reason, even if it's just code readability, not necessarily execution time.

Comment: Exactly. So forget about code execution time or memory. Whichever one more cleanly expresses the intent of the programmer should be chosen.

Comment: Preemptive microoptimization is never a good idea. Microoptimizations do nothing 95% of the time. If you're gonna microoptimize, first identify that you have a bottleneck, then profile your code, then make adjustments, measure, and make sure they're effective. When you're writing code, readibility and such is key.

Comment: @AnubianNoob and which one is more readible in what situations?

Comment: It's super subjective. As a generalization writing code that depends on short circuiting (ie having a method call as the second operand of the &&) is confusing. But if you have just two variables in there it doesn't matter. Again, super subjective.

Comment: @Aequitas For example, if `a` and `b` are just booleans, the `(a && b)` is probably much better. But if `b` is really a function call and the `//code` is not that important to emphasize, the second option may be better because it emphasizes the conditions under which `b` is called and it gives you a place to comment on `b`.

Answer (score 8):

They get compiled to the same bytecode. No performance difference.

Readability is the only difference. As a huge generalization, short-circuiting looks better but nesting is slightly clearer. It really boils down to the specific use case. I'd typically short-circuit.

---

I tried this out. Here's the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a = 1>0;
        boolean b = 0>1;

        if (a && b)
            System.out.println(5);

        if (a)
            if (b)
                System.out.println(5);
    }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
  0: iconst_1
  1: istore_1
  2: iconst_0
  3: istore_2
  4: iload_1
  5: ifeq          19
  8: iload_2
  9: ifeq          19
 12: getstatic     #2
 15: iconst_5
 16: invokevirtual #3
 19: iload_1
 20: ifeq          34
 23: iload_2
 24: ifeq          34
 27: getstatic     #2
 30: iconst_5
 31: invokevirtual #3
 34: return
```

Note how this block repeats twice:

```
  4: iload_1
  5: ifeq          19
  8: iload_2
  9: ifeq          19
 12: getstatic     #2
 15: iconst_5
 16: invokevirtual #3
```

Same bytecode both times.

Answer (score 4):

It makes a difference if you have an **else** associated with each **if**.

```
if(a && b)
{
     //do something if both a and b evaluate to true
} else {
    //do something if either of a or b is false
}
```

and this:

```
if(a)
{
     if(b)
     {
          //do something if both a and b are true
     } else {
          //do something if only a is true
     }
} else {
     if(b)
     {
          //do something if only b is true
     } else {
          //do something if both a and b are false
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing in between two `if` statements in your second example then definitely first one is more cleaner and more readable.

But if there is a piece of code that could fit in between the two if conditions then only way is second example.

Comment: if you have code that should run after a but before b then you can put it into a method c that returns true.  then you can use short circuit notation a && c() && b

Answer (score 0):

there shouldn't be a difference, but in readability I would prefer the first one, because it is less verbose and less indented.